# Responsive Webdesign with Bootstrap: Equal height boxes for 3-column and 2-column grid layout

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am using Bootstrap 3.2.0 and I have a grid design with 6 boxes.

The first three boxes have more content than the last three ones.

For large screens sizes I have a 3-column layout, for medium screens sizes 2-column and small one 1-column. The 1-column layout is not the problem, because all boxes will be positioned vertically.

For the 3-column layout the boxes 1, 2 and 3 should be positioned in one row with equal heights. The same for boxes 4, 5 and 6: in one row below the first row and with equal heights.

For the 2-colums layout the boxes 1 and 2 should be in one, boxes 3 and 4,5 should be in one row and box 6 in the last row on the left hand side.

You can see this what I wanted to have in this picture:
[image: Layout 3-column and 2 column layout]

I made a fiddle so you can see what I did:
http://jsfiddle.net/5tJk3/

Here is the code snippet:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row-fluid">
        <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4">
            <div class="bs-grid-big">
                Box 1
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4">
            <div class="bs-grid-big">
                Box 2
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4">
            <div class="bs-grid-big">
                Box 3
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row-fluid">
        <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4">
            <div class="bs-grid-small">
                Box 4
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4">
            <div class="bs-grid-small">
                Box 5
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4">
            <div class="bs-grid-small">
                Box 6
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Is there an easy way to do this with Bootstrap? I think the 2-column layout will be hard to get box 4 and 5 to an equal height with box 3.

Comment: You can do this with the help of jQuery/JavaScript... Only because you would need to continuously keep adjusting the height of the boxes as you change the screen sizes.

Comment: But would it be only one row I could use some techniques like shown on this web page, right? http://css-tricks.com/fluid-width-equal-height-columns/ Are there any JavaScript libraries I can use which will fit for my scenario?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the awesome `.hidden-sm .clearfix` combo trick, by putting it in an empty div after your 5th column. It will clearfix ONLY on sm devices, placing your 6th column on the left. No Custom CSS needed.

```
<div class="visible-sm clearfix"></div>
 <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4">Column 6 Lorem Ipsum
...
```

**Demo: http://www.bootply.com/mYKLVnKl0k**

Comment: But if all boxes do have different sizes because of different content, there are not so well-aligned? I changed the content and it seems not to be what I want to have: http://www.bootply.com/qD3X5KOL5g# There are no equal height columns. I did a jsfiddle which works, but unfortunately with a lot of JavaScript and libraries: http://jsfiddle.net/rp38Z/5/

Comment: I see. I didn't pickup on the fact that you want boxes 4&5 to take up the same amount of vertical space as box 3, no matter each of their contents.

Comment: They are on the same row though, like you wanted, so I bet it would take less js and custom css to then make them equal height...

Answer (score 1):

here is what i did
I put fixed height on .bs-grid-big and half of it to .bs-grid-small + additional 20px to .bs-grid-big since you have h2 inside of small and it gives margin top 20px.

```
(http://jsfiddle.net/5tJk3/1/)
```

Is this what you want? 
And you should check out jquery match height plugin

```
(http://brm.io/jquery-match-height/)
```

Comment: The content is dynamic and so the height of the boxes too. So I can not set fixed heights, I want to have it responsive. The second link seems to be interesting, so I can achieve the 3-column layout, but I don not know how can it be done with the 2-column layout with boxes 4 and 5 same height as box 3.

Comment: you can read the height of the big div with jquery, divide it by 2 and set that number to be the height of the smaller div

Comment: I integrated the `jQuery Match Height` here: http://jsfiddle.net/d8w2n/ It works great for 1 column and 3 column layout. The problem is the 2 column layout. Is there a default way to do it with this small library?

Comment: I did it this way with this plugin and some calculcations: http://jsfiddle.net/rp38Z/1/ What do you think?

Comment: Here you can see the new version http://jsfiddle.net/rp38Z/5/ There was a little bug with some calculations with Safari. Thank you for your hint with `jquery-match-height`.